# Minecraft is havinng size problems in elemenry os

Tags: graphics, window-management, apps, window-manager, games

i downloaded Minevtaft to play it on my Elementry os system.
When i installed the game and open it this happened:
[image: The issue]

And when i close and re-open the game. window is becoming smaller and smaller. The resson why i post here is i tryed playing minecraft on ubuntu that works here but idk why but the game is not  working correctly here.

> **Edit:** İ Solved the problem by downloading an other launcher that supports original minecraft accounts. No Help Needed

Comment: I have same problem but nothing helps me. I tried install from different type packages. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RViIJ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RViIJ.jpg)

Comment: Problem solved on deb package

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

If you do play Minecraft, the launcher for the game has an issue with it's window shadow. This can be fixed easily. Type in this command in terminal:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/minecraft-launcher.desktop
```

find line "Exec"

[image]

and add: env GTK_CSD=0

[image]

save file and lunch minecraft